# Flutter application throws Http Exception and instantly crashes

Tags: android, dart, flutter, httpexception

currently I'm having a problem with running flutter applications. I tried to search solutions, but none of them was actually my case. The problem is, when I try to install an application, sometimes it starts running, but instantly crashes, or not even build, and throws this exception (even with flutter demo project):

```
Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:57564/ws".
```

What I've tried so far: Cleaning cashes, reinstall flutter/android studio. I got this problem only with a few (android os) mobile. 
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text("App"))),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy in your network?

Comment: I think you should post the whole code to let us understand where the error is!

Comment: I posted code, and as you can see, it's very-very simple. I don't use http anywhere, btw, this error happens every time, it doesn't matter what the code is

Comment: I solved it by setting a mobile device and laptop on the same wifi network. Sometimes I need to restart the mobile device.

Comment: I have already tried these. None of them solve the problem

Comment: I have the same problem, if you happen to solve this somehow please answer your own question.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem creating a new emulator device but NOT using the most recent Android Image.

Android Studio > Configure > AVD Manager > Create Virtual Device > (Choose a device model) > (Select a system image, but NOT the most recent)

In my case, I had the following Android images as choices: Q, Pie 28, Oreo 27 and 26, etc.
I selected Pie 28 and the problem was solved. The problem was occuring with Android Q (most recent).

Comment: I don't think this fixed it. I'm not on Android Q and I have this problem too and creating a new virtual device didn't fix it for me.

Comment: @Loolooii Did you try API version 28? Curious if that works for you.

Comment: @dustinrwh This problem went away when I removed one of the plugins I was using. I just tried removing them one by one. Specifically it was `flutter_webview_plugin` causing this problem apparently. I'm not sure if your issue is also caused by something like this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the API version. Choose 28 It fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I use a real device and my problem was only solved when I deleted a plugin from `pubspec.yaml` file. Maybe this can help.